# How to assert element before request returns?

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

Using Angular and Playwright

I have 2 buttons... delete mode button  and refresh button. When the user refreshes the button, I have the delete mode button disabled. When the request comes back, I re enable the  delete mode button.

How can I write a test to where I hit the refresh button, I can assert the delete mode button is disabled before the request (which is mocked) is returned?

I have the below but the assertion always passes even if I add a `.not` to try and fail it (false positive).

```js
it('should disable delete button during refresh', async ({ page }) => {
  const deleteBtn = page.getByRole('button', {name: 'enter delete mode'}).first();
  page.on('request', () => { expect(deleteBtn).toBeDisabled() }) // false positive
  await page.getByText('REFRESH', { exact: true}).click();
});
```

Comment: Which request are you sending? `page.on("request"` is dangerous, because there are other requests that can be in flight than the one you want to target. I'd make sure there's an `if` in there, and then don't allow the request to continue until you've asserted the disabled state. You'll also need to connect the main promise with the callback promise so the test doesn't end until the callback runs. Asserting button enabled at the end may be enough. A [mcve] of the component behavior would be useful. Using `.first()` is discouraged and there should be a more precise selector there, by the way.

Comment: That is a side effect of angular material, I have to use first(). What am I testing with the `if` to not allow the request to continue?

Comment: I would check the request URL to make sure it's the correct one before asserting that the button is disabled.

Comment: What about 'don't allow the request to continue until you've asserted the disabled state'? How would I do that?

Comment: I suggested "Asserting button enabled at the end may be enough". Did you try that? if that's not clear enough, add `expect(deleteBtn).toBeEnabled()` at the end of the block.

Comment: That will not work... because the button is enabled before the request is made. The button is only disabled during the request until the request is complete. At the end of a test, the button will always be enabled.

Comment: You're right, you'll need a way to ensure that the `expect(deleteBtn).toBeDisabled()` runs first in the same promise chain as the final `expect(deleteBtn).toBeEnabled()`. I'll write an answer if I can, but keep in mind I'll be inventing a sample page which may not match your actual use case. That's why it's good to provide a mock page, or better yet, the actual page, so we have an agreed-upon minimal, reproducible scenario to collaborate on, without ambiguity or guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept the network request and mock its response, ensuring that there is a guaranteed window to catch the button in the state where it's supposed to be disabled. Mocking also helps connect the assertion happening in the callback with the main line promise chain in the test case so that the test doesn't end before the assertion has a chance to run.

Here's a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button>enter delete mode</button>
<button>REFRESH</button>
<script>
const [deleteModeBtn, refreshBtn] = document.querySelectorAll("button");
refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  deleteModeBtn.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .finally(() => {
      deleteModeBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("button is disabled during the request", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const btn = page.getByRole("button", {name: "enter delete mode"});
  await page.route("*/**/users", async route => {
    await expect(btn).toBeDisabled();
    await route.fulfill({});
  });
  await expect(btn).toBeEnabled();
  await page.getByText("REFRESH", {exact: true}).click();
  await expect(btn).toBeEnabled();
});
```

To ensure this test actually validates the button being disabled when the request is in flight, comment out `btn.setAttribute("disabled", true)` or `btn.removeAttribute("disabled")` and the test will fail.